# language-haskell in atom only recognizes packages in Prelude

Tags: haskell, atom-editor

I use [`language-haskell`](https://atom.io/packages/language-haskell) package to turn my atom into a haskell aware text editor. In a `.hs` file when I try to import a package which is not in prelude e.g.:

```
import Control.Monad.Random
```

I get the following error:

> Could not find module ‘Control.Monad.Random’ Use -v to see a list of
>   the files searched for.

There seems to be a problem with `language-haskell` package.
info: I am running a Mac OS X El Captain

Comment: By which means did you install the [MonadRandom package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom)? Cabal, stack...?

Comment: I installed a full haskell package. I didn't install MoandRandom alone. when I load the script to ghci it works just fine.

Comment: I found out that the problem is with ide-haskell. I will submit an issue in their github.